# How to get single row from multiple rows having same ID?

Tags: sql

I have multiple rows for same ID. How to display any one row per unique ID?

I tried

```
select Col_1, Col_2, Col_3 from Table group by Col_1.
```

But this throws error saying, Col_2 and Col_3 is not in group by clause ( I wonder if syntax is wrong )

this is the given table

```
Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
1        A       B
1        B       A
2        C       D
2        D       C
```

Expected Output

```
Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
1        A       B
2        C       D
```

Comment: What specific database technology are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL? MSSQL? Etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close... when using group by , columns that are not part of the grouping statement must be part of an aggregate function. As such you can do something like:

```
select Col_1, Max(Col_2), Max(Col_3) from Table group by Col_1
```

I used the max Aggregation function here, but you can use any function you want. The above should get you what you are looking for and should run on most DBs

Comment: Note that for the sample data, this returns the row `1 B B`, which doesn't correspond exactly to any one of the rows (`1 A B` and `1 B A`) in the data.  It isn't clear whether that matters.  You (@DwightK) have now learned why primary keys are important — they allow you to get at information in a row accurately.  Make sure your tables have primary keys.

Comment: @DwightK . . . I am baffled at how this "works" when it doesn't produce the output requested in the question.

Comment: Same ... Max on a string should also either not work ... or return the max string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Col_2, t.Col_3

FROM table as t

ORDER BY t.Col_1
```